# Understanding Bra Ket notation with two items inside.

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

When working in quantum mechanics, an operator can be written as a "ket".
$\left| n \right> $

However, what does it mean when we have two items inside the ket? Such as $\left| l ,m \right>$. My notes say that *"Here we adopt the Dirac notation in a way such that $\left|l,m\right> \equiv \psi^l_m$"*. I am confused as to what $\left| l ,m \right>$ is. Does it have something to do with there now being two dimensions? How would lowering and raising operators work on it?

Comment: The $l$ and $m$ are not tensor indices.

Comment: A *state* is written as a ket, an operator would be ket-bra $\left| ... \right> \left< ... \right|$. The labels within the ket label eigenvalues of operators for which the ket is an eigenket. In this case, it is (most likely: context required to be sure) an eigenket of $L^2$ with eigenvalue related to $l$ and an eigenket of $L_z$ with eigenvalue $m$. The number of labels corresponds to the number of [commuting observables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_set_of_commuting_observables) required to fully specify a state, and is not directly linked to spatial dimension.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it have something to do with there now being two dimensions?

Hamiltonians with symmetrical 2D potentials that we can solve explicitly often have eigenfunctions that can be naturally labeled by two parameters. If we have an irregular potential ("random" bumps and valleys), there will not necessarily be a natural two parameter labeling. In either case, they are just labels - we could label them $\left| a \right>, \left| b \right>, \left| c \right>, $ ... .